# how to use lodash to sum data with the same key?

Tags: lodash

I have data like this:

```
var data = [
{2: 1, 6: 1},
{2: 2},
{1: 3, 6: 2},
```

];

(the "2" is like a key and "1" means  "count")

and I want to output like this:

```
output = [
{2: 3, 6: 3, 1: 3},
```

];

is there a way to archive this by using lodash?

Comment: Relevant: [Combine objects with the same key with lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576674/combine-objects-with-the-same-key-with-lodash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#mergeWith) with spread to merge all keys and sum their values:

```js
const data = [{2: 1, 6: 1}, {2: 2}, {1: 3, 6: 2}];

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...data, (objValue, srcValue) =>
  _.isNumber(objValue) ? objValue + srcValue : srcValue);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```